# Como retornar todos os objetos de um array JSON

Tags: javascript, json, http-request

tenho uma API que retorna um array, contendo valores do tipo:

```
[
    {
        "nome": "JOSE"
    },
    {
        "nome": "MARIA"
    },
    {
        "nome": "SERGIO"
    }
]
```

Preciso retornar de forma que eu consiga exibir as informações
tipo:
Nome :JOSÉ
Nome :Maria
Nome :Sergio

Como eu faço isso?

Já quebrei cabeça aqui, mas não consegui nenhuma forma…
Obrigado!

Segue o código da forma que to tentando fazer, alguém

```js
const rp = require('request-promise');

function main(params) {
    // if (!params.name)
    // {
    //     return { message: 'Nome não encontrado.' };
    // }
    return rp({
        method: 'GET',
        uri: `URL AQUI`,
        json: true,
    })
    .then(body => {
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {//coloquei até 10 só pra testar
            var result = [];
            console.log(i);
            console.log(body.recordsets[0].length);
             console.log(body.recordset[i]);
             result.push(body.recordset[i]); // aqui eu tento colocar no array que criei em cima 
         }
        return result[0] ;
    })
    .catch(err => {
        return err;
    });
}
```

EDIT @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@

VOLTANDO SÓ PRA AGRADECER E FALAR QUE O CODE FICOU ASSIM:

```
Bom galera, muito obrigado pela ajudar, o code ficou assim:



<!-- language: lang-js -->

    const rp = require('request-promise');

    function main(params) {
        // if (!params.name)
        // {
        //     return { message: 'Nome não encontrado.' };
        // }
        return rp({
            method: 'GET',
            uri: `.....`,
            json: true,
        })
            .then(body => {
                var result = {'name' :[]};
                body.forEach((item) => {
                    Object.keys(item).forEach((propriedade) => {
                        result.name.push(item[propriedade])
                        console.log(propriedade, ' -> ', item[propriedade])
                    })
                })
               
                
                return result;
            })
            .catch(err => {
                return err;
            });
    }




<!-- end snippet -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para entender melhor como fazer, basta primeiro entender a estrutura (depois o resto fica fácil).

O que você tem é um array, pois está delimitado por colchetes. Em um array, os elementos ficam entre `[ ]` e separados por vírgula.

Dentro do array, cada elemento é um objeto, pois está delimitado por chaves. Por exemplo, `{ "nome": "JOSE" }` é um objeto cuja chave "nome" possui o valor "JOSE".

Então neste array temos 3 elementos, e cada um deles é um objeto com a chave "nome":

```
[ <-- início do array
    { "nome": "JOSE" },  <-- primeiro elemento do array
    { "nome": "MARIA" },  <-- segundo elemento do array
    { "nome": "SERGIO" }  <-- terceiro elemento do array
] <-- fim do array
```

Para percorrer arrays, basta usar um `for`, e para acessar a chave `nome`, basta usar o próprio nome dela:

```js
let nomes = [
    { "nome": "JOSE" },
    { "nome": "MARIA" },
    { "nome": "SERGIO" }
];

for (const obj of nomes) { // para cada elemento do array, imprime o nome
    console.log(`Nome=${obj.nome}`);
}
```

A saída é:

```
Nome=JOSE
Nome=MARIA
Nome=SERGIO
```

---

Como [você disse](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/466555/como-retornar-todos-os-objetos-de-um-array-json/466558#comment881704_466558) que quer "juntar" os nomes em uma única estrutura, uma opção é colocar todos os nomes em um único array:

```js
let nomes = [
    { "nome": "JOSE" },
    { "nome": "MARIA" },
    { "nome": "SERGIO" }
];

let result = { 'nomes': [] }; // começa com um array vazio: []
for (const obj of nomes) { // adiciona os nomes no array acima
    result.nomes.push(obj.nome);
}
console.log(result); // { nomes: [ 'JOSE', 'MARIA', 'SERGIO' ] }

// outra opção é usar map:
result = { 'nomes': nomes.map(obj => obj.nome) };
console.log(result); // { nomes: [ 'JOSE', 'MARIA', 'SERGIO' ] }
```

Assim, o resultado é um objeto com a chave "nomes", cujo valor é um array contendo todos os nomes do array original.

---

A solução da [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/466558/112052) é mais geral, caso os objetos tenham mais de uma chave. Mas se a ideia é pegar somente a chave "nome", basta acessá-la diretamente.

Comment: Exatamente isso, eu conseguir fazendo uma gambiarra aqui, mas com certeza irei alterar e fazer  direito

Answer (score 1):

Olá,

o que você está procurando é [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), ele retorna um array com as propriedade de um objeto passado como parâmetro.

```
let nomes = [
  {
    "nome": "JOSE"
  },
  {
    "nome": "MARIA"
  },
  {
    "nome": "SERGIO"
  }
];

// para cada objeto, leremos as propriedades e printaremos no console.
nomes.forEach((item) => {
  Object.keys(item).forEach((propriedade) => {
    console.log(propriedade, ' -> ', item[propriedade])
  })  
})
```

resultará em

```
nome  ->  JOSE
nome  ->  MARIA
nome  ->  SERGIO
```

Comment: Fantastico é isso porém a minha requisição só aceita que o return seja um obj JSON e eu não faço ideia como fazer pensei em alguma saida do tipo:
{
"name": "JOSE","MARIA,"SERGIO"
} 
isso é possível?

Comment: @EmersonFerreiravc precisa retornar todo os nomes juntos? esse seu retorno é um json inválido, pode confirmar como vc precisa?

Comment: Exatamente, @h3nr1ke preciso de todos os nomes juntos, to tentando de tudo mas não consigo, a estrutura é algo parecido com { "name": "JOSE","MARIA","SERGIO", ...} até não houver mais itens à adicionar

Comment: para ser válido teria de ser algo como {name: "Jose, Maria, Sergio"} ou ainda {name: ["jose", "maria", "sergio"]}, qual desses vc busca?

Comment: Esses são os processos relacionados a sua àrea: [{"name":"CON001 - Consulta por CPF"},{"name":"AUX004 - Prevent Screen Lock"},{"name":"EMAIL002 - Envio de e-mail"},{"name":"EMAIL000 - POP3/SMTP"}] atualmente essa é minha resposta e eu queria deixar mais harmonioso com apenas 1 field "name" e todos os nomes dentro dele, consegues me entender?

Comment: Não muito =(, a estrutura que vc mostra é realmente muito comum e sinceramente não vejo o porque de tratar esse retorno, ao meu ver já está bom, quando fizer um loop para exibir onde precisar, acredito que não tenha problema, talvez retrabalhar este retorno seja "complicar" o seu trabalho. Mas prosseguindo, ao meu ver, essa estrutura seja a que vc procura, assim teria apenas um field name e um array simples dentrto {name: ["jose", "maria", "sergio"]}, vc poderia exibir todos junto utilizando objeto.name.join(',') por exemplo e exibir todos juntos